# Regular Expression for min and max characters, no spaces

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, passwords

I need to verify that a string contains a minimum of 6 characters and maximum 8 characters, containing no spaces. Any alphanumeric characters can be used in the string.

I'm using asp.net with C3 and I will user Regular Expression validation for this purpose .

Comment: Please post the relevant section of the code that you're currently working on; folks will be glad to help, but won't write it for you. In addition, include whatever samples you're using as a corpus to test against.

Comment: Add the language you are working on (some languages have different syntax), show what have you tried.

Comment: Do not restrict the characters allowable in a password or maximum length; only check for minimum length.

Comment: @Ianzz: I couldn't agree with you more

Comment: `alphanumeric characters can be used` makes `containing no spaces` redundant. Space is neither alpha nor numeric.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to enforce restrictions on passwords at all, barring a restriction on *minimum* length. You should be storing **hashes** of passwords, in which case the length is mostly immaterial. If you want to restrict password length so you can store the passwords in an 8-character database field (or similar), you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Cyborgx37: I beg to differ. If he's building a front-end for a lame system, he should specify that. 90% of the time, questions asking for a solution to a ill-formed problem are asked because the person asking the question *doesn't know there's a better way*. It's our duty to provide not only an answer to the question as asked, but also to provide guidance on why doing it that way is a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

The regex `^\w{6,8}$` should do the job:

- `^` - start of string
- `\w` - word character

  - `{6,8}` - 6 to 8 times
- `$` - end of string

---

As Ianzz said in a comment, you really shouldn't restrict what your users can use as passwords:

> Do not restrict the characters allowable in a password or maximum length; only check for minimum length.

Comment: It would only check that _somewhere in the password_ there is a substring of word characters of length 6 to 8. It is not anchored at the start and end of the string.

Comment: You need some positional anchors in there. You probably wanted `/^\w{6,8}$/`. And the `i` flag is superfluous.

Comment: @lanzz: good catch, I actually didn't see that until I looked closer.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` in at least Python and PCRE (note the underscore.) It also matches the "local" word characters for international users (in Python, Russian users will get ` \w` that allows Cyrillic characters.)

Comment: _"It also matches the "local" word characters"_ - that was why I switched

Comment: The parser means everything. Get rid of the extraneous "/" characters. They are not part of the standard regex syntax. (+1 for the element descriptions)

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a pretty simple expression to match against. You may need to tweak this a bit if your regex engine doesn't support intervals.

```
/(?x)
  ^            # start of string
  [[:alnum:]]  # POSIX alphanumeric class
  {6,8}        # minimum 6 matches, maximum 8
  $            # end of string
/
```

This works for me in the Ruby REPL. Your regex engine's synax may differ, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which language you are using, but it should not matter much in this case.

I'm assuming Javascript, so that would be:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{6,8}$/i
```

the //i is to ignore case. You could also use:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,8}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown any work done I'll give you the pieces but it's up to you to figure out how they go together.

alphanumeric characters can be represented by `[a-zA-Z0-9]` or usually also by `\w`
(edited this part because the correct comments below, mea culpa)

the beginning of a sentence is marked by ^  and the ending by $

a quantity qualifier of 6-8 is expressed as such `{[min],[max]}` where `[min]` and `[max]` need to be replaced by the obvious numbers

depending of the type of regexp you may also need to enclose it with boundaries, convention usually favours `/` so your regep would be  `/[regexp here]/`

With these you can piece your expression together. Have fun. :)

Comment: Your "alphanumeric characters" class actually contains commas as well.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson. The character class `[a-z,A-Z,0-9]` also matches commas. And `\w` also (usually) matches underscores.

Comment: true, forgot about. Sorry. :)